# Could recovering mysql data on another server affect performance?

Tags: mysql, database, filesystems, storage

Suppose I have 2 MySQL servers: S1 and S2 (They could be on different machines). I **don't take a  db dump** but rather directly make a copy of S1's data directory and put it in S2's data directory.

My question is, if the disk storage on S2 is somewhat fragmented, will it degrade the performance of the S2 server with respect to the S1 server, or database servers have built-in mechanisms to handle such scenarios?

Comment: I think MySQL just uses normal filesystem interfacees, so if the OS performance is poor, it will slow down the DB.

Comment: Not a lot; don't worry.  You may need to worry about whether you copied enough stuff.